# Does the order of FILTER statement affect the performance of query in arangoDB?

Tags: database, performance, arangodb, aql

For example, I have this data structure

```
{
easyFilter:1111,
hardFilter:[
 {id:1},
 {id:2},
...
]
}
```

If the query I use is like

```
For u in collection
Filter u.easyFilter=1111 AND "somevalue" IN FLATTEN(u.hardFilter[*].id)
return u
```

Will the query run faster if I place `easyFilter` first since it just string comparison on the first level of a object or it does not matter in arango?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, order of FILTER statements does affect performance of query.

Especially in your case, where

`easyFilter` is just string comparison,

while `hardFilter` is constructed from multiple operations

1. iterating array + getting values of defined key
2. flattening that array
3. checking if array contains defined value

What's omitted is the importance of indexes. They are THE one behind truly performat queries. Check [Handling Indexes](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Indexing/) in [ArangoDB documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/), especially [Which Index to use when](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Indexing/WhichIndex.html).

For improving performance of your example would be definitely helpful to add [Hash](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Indexing/Hash.html) or [Skiplist](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Indexing/Skiplist.html) index easyFilter (depends on type / uniqueness of your data). Both indexes support also arrays, but based on documentation, that applies only to simple arrays containing values, not objects.

Comment: You can create an index `hardFilter[*].id` and do `FILTER 1234 IN u.hardFilter[*].id` in a query (no need for `FLATTEN()`) to utilize a hash or skiplist index. It will match any document which has at least the given ID, nested in the hardFilter attribute. Note that the optimizer can not make use of a skiplist index in combination with a range comparison (yet), like `FILTER u.hardFilter[*].id ALL >= 1234`.